# Toggling between divs (close one that is already open upon clicking another)

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm new to jQuery and have been stuck on this problem for days now! I have a few buttons in a nav bar that are supposed to open specific divs below. I used slideToggle to open them, which is working well. However, if "la carte" is open, and I click on "les addresses," the div for "la carte" stays open! How do I make it so that if you click on one button, whatever div is already open will close? Please help!!

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div class="nav">
<ul>
<li id="t-menu"><a id="button">la carte</button></li>
<li id="t-adresses"><a id="button2">les adresses</a></li>
<li id="t-presse"><a id="button3">la presse</a></li>
<li id="t-contact"><a id="button4">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="menu">
<p>5 euro sandwichs | 6 euro salades</p>

<ul>

    <li class="first"><strong>L'Original</strong><br>houmous, carottes, dés d'aubergine, salade</li>

    <li class="item"><strong>Le Grec</strong><br>tapenade olives-tomate, oignons rouges, fromage, salade</li>

    <li class="item"><strong>Le Redneck</strong><br>sauce philadelphia barbecue, tomate, mais, cornichon</li>


    <li class="noborder"><strong>Le Veggie Fest</strong><br>tapenade aubergines, carottes, mais, salade</li>

    <li class="middle"><strong>Le Provençal</strong><br>caviar de tomates, crème d'artichaut, concombre, carottes, dés d'aubergine</li>

    <li class="middle"><strong>Attention</strong><br>traces de sésame et de noix</li>


</ul>

</div>

<div id="map">

    <h3>Notre addresse</h3>
    <p>On se trouve à 17 Rue d'Algérie à Lyon</p>
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=17%20Rue%20d'Alg%C3%A9rie%2C%20Lyon%2C%20France&key=AIzaSyAKr9uzWTir1ejce2UfXBIfX1R1UcWQsoM"></iframe>

<p>D'autres locaux à venir!</p>

    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var par=$("#menu").hide();

    $("#button").click(function(e){
        $("#menu").slideToggle("slow");

            e.preventDefault();

});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var par =$("#map").hide();

    $("#button2").click(function(e){
        $("#map").slideToggle(500);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: You can use `slideUp` and `slideDown` respectively. Example: `if ( $("#map").is(":visible") ) { $("#map").slideUp(); $("#menu").slideDown(); }`

Comment: Thank you! Would you just put that underneath the functions?

Comment: You would put that in your respective button click handlers i.e. `$("#button2").click(function(e) { // put here });`

Comment: Also, this is a good solution for having two div's to manage, however, if you had a ton more, you'd want to use a better strategy like using the `class` and `data` attributes to link buttons and divs, with a universal function that manages the showing/hiding.

Comment: Thanks, it's still not working, though.

Comment: Here's a working example for you: The HTML: `<input type="button" id="button1" value="Show Map" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Show Menu" />
<div id="map" style="display: none; width: 500px; height: 300px; background: blue;"></div>
<div id="menu" style="display: none; width: 500px; height: 300px; background: yellow;"></div>`

Comment: The jQuery: `function toggleDivs(thisDiv, otherDiv) {
    if (thisDiv.is(":hidden")) {
        if(otherDiv.is(":visible")) {
            otherDiv.slideUp(200, function() {
                thisDiv.slideDown(200); 
            });
        }
        else {
             thisDiv.slideDown(200);   
        }
    }
    else {
         return false;   
    }
}

$("#button1").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   toggleDivs($("#map"), $("#menu"));
});
$("#button2").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   toggleDivs($("#menu"), $("#map"));
});`